# Rails Webbrick simultaneous connections are they supposed to stack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver

Im using the standard Ruby-on-Rails `WEBBRICK` server.

Im testing and If I have two or three connections simultaneously on very intensive scripts (which I let fully execute without timeouts) is it normal for them to stack (i.e complete the next task once the previous one completes - many simultaneous connections but only one is processed at a go)?

1) Is this behaviour normal?
2) How would I escape this, is `Thin` recommendable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails server (webrick) is really only intended for local testing in development; a single instance runs, and requests will block on each other.  Thin is a better choice as it does know how to handle multiple processes.  Some people use Apache or Nginx in front of Thin for production servers.  Passenger is a similar option that is also popular.

So yeah, install Thin for more realistic testing.

P.S. If you are hosting on Amazon EC2, their micro- and small instances only have a single CPU, so even if you have multiple processes accepting requests, if they are bound by the CPU, they'll act as though they are blocking on each other.  (This may not be relevant to your question, but several long days of my life were spent figuring this out :-).

Comment: I like the behaviour, im using it for a cron so I'd like it to execute in a stack style. I wish to use it in a production environ but the rails app itself with thin!

Comment: I would strongly consider writing rake tasks, instead and calling them from cron.  If there are dependencies between the tasks, then you could build a rake task that models and enforces the dependencies.  Building a rake task is a snap (I used to think there was some magic, but it's just more ruby code).  That's the way to go.

Comment: I'll have a look. I asked a while back here on whether it was optimal I had no clue such a thing existed